# Binding command on behavior with a converter

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, behavior, ivalueconverter

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project.

I have a behavior on a listview, which is doing a binding on a command with a converter. I did it with XAML and C# and it's working perfectly.

***XAML part :***

```
<ListView.Behaviors>
  <bh:ListViewPagingBehavior
    Command="{Binding LoadMoreLeadOfTheDateCommand}"
    Converter="{StaticResource ItemVisibilityConverter}">
  </bh:ListViewPagingBehavior>
</ListView.Behaviors>
```

But now i need to do this process on code-behind only, cause i needed to create my listview in the code-behind.

***I tried to traduce this XAML like this :***

```
ListViewPagingBehavior behavior = new ListViewPagingBehavior();
behavior.SetBinding(ListViewPagingBehavior.CommandProperty, "LoadMoreLeadOfTheDateCommand", BindingMode.Default, new ItemVisibilityEventArgsConverter());
myListView.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

Unfortunatly, the IValueConverter doesn't retrieve the same parameters as before on the Convert() method...

***My Converter :***

```
public class ItemVisibilityEventArgsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var eventArgs = value as ItemVisibilityEventArgs;
        return eventArgs.Item;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

***Good parameters of Convert() with the working code :***

- value = Xamarin.Forms.ItemVisibilityEventArgs
- targetType = System.Object
- parameter  = null
- culture    = null

***Bad parameters of Convert() with my all C# code :***

- value = DelegateCommand
- targetType = ICommand
- parameter  = null
- culture    = {fr-FR}

Can someone tell me where am i wrong ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've reproduced your case well enough, but here's the thing I came up with.

```
behavior.SetBinding(ListViewPagingBehavior.CommandProperty, "LoadMoreLeadOfTheDateCommand", BindingMode.Default, new ItemVisibilityEventArgsConverter());
```

Here you're using your converter to convert what you're binding, and that means you're converting "LoadMoreLeadOfTheDateCommand". That's why you get DelegateCommand as value. Your binding should look like this:

```
behavior.SetBinding(ListViewPagingBehavior.CommandProperty, "LoadMoreLeadOfTheDateCommand");
```

And then just use your behavior's ConverterProperty (or whatever you've called it):

```
behavior.Converter = new ItemVisibilityEventArgsConverter();
```

By the way that is what you're doing in your XAML. Anyway that works for me and I hope it'll work for you also :)

Comment: I don't know why, I didn't saw that the behavior has a converter property. It's working perfectly now. Thank you for your time maddhew :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `ListViewPagingBehavior` so I can only guess, but looking at this syntax:

```xml
<ListView.Behaviors>
  <bh:ListViewPagingBehavior
    Command="{Binding LoadMoreLeadOfTheDateCommand}"
    Converter="{StaticResource ItemVisibilityConverter}">
  </bh:ListViewPagingBehavior>
</ListView.Behaviors>
```

the `Converter` is a property of the `ListViewPagingBehavior` and not a property of the `{Binding}` (having a visibility converter to converter would seem very strange, on the other hand).

The equivalent C# for this would look like this:

```cs
var behavior = new ListViewPageBindingBehavior();
behavior.SetBinding(ListViewPageBindingBehavior.CommandProperty, "LoadMoreLeadOfTheDateCommand");
behavior.Converter = new ItemVisibilityConverter();

myListView.Behaviors.Add (behavior);
```

Comment: That's it, i didn't saw the behavior's converter property . Thank you very much, it's working now !